# Multiple users using same Servlets will they override eachothers variables?

Tags: java, servlets

I'm making calls to the Java backend through servlets and for each call to the API im using i need to supply password and username. Can I save the users password/username in a variable so I can use it every time the user makes a call to the API?

Or will the variable be overwritten if there are multiple users?

The overall question perhaps is: Does every user get new "fresh" servlets or is the data saved from the users before?

Comment: Servlets execute requests on per thread basis, so NO data is not saved from previous request. You can use session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Servlets are shared for performance reasons, so they should be stateless (or thread-safe, but then you'd just be reinventing the wheel). If you need to keep state with a user, put it into `HttpSession`.

Answer (score 0):

> Does every user get new "fresh" servlets or is the data saved from the
>   users before?

**Servlet instance will be created only once** (unless you are doing something differently like using `SingleThreadModel`) & maintained by the container (like Tomcat, etc..), i.e., one single servlet instance is going to be used/shared by all requests.

So, don't use the servlet's instance variables to store any data.

> Can I save the users password/username in a variable so I can use it
>   every time the user makes a call to the API?

You shouldn't be saving userids and passwords into JVM (RAM) memory because **you will loose all of the data when the JVM shuts down**, so you need to use some **persistent store like a database** (prefer this) or file system.

Answer (score 0):

If you use static variables then the variables got shared across the users. Also, it's a concurrency issue and you need to handle it. If the variables are not static then each user would have an excluded instance.

Anyway, If you want to store some information and you want to retrieve them in the future when a specific user call the servlet then it's common to use HttpSession. Also, consider that you need to grab the http cookie in your client and send it to the server for the further calls.

Also, it's a common scenario that server provides an API key for each client. Then whenever the client wants to call an API; it's necessary to send the key through a specific http header.

The above scenario would have some security issues if you don't use a secure connection like HTTPS between server and clients.